# Homographie Opencv apply in Opengl

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, homography

I modified a algorithm to rectif. It returns me 2 Opencv homographies (3x3 Matrixes). I can use cv::warpPerspective and get rectified images. So the algorithm works right. But I need to apply this homographies to textures in OpenGl. So I create a 4x4 Matrix (HomoGl) and I use

```
glMultMatrixf(HomoGl);
```

to apply this Tranform. To fill HomoGl I use

```
for(int i=0;i<3;++i){
    for(int j=0; j<3;++j){
        HomoGL[i+j*4] =  HomoCV.at<double>(i,j);
    }
}
```

This methode has the best result...but it is wrong. I test some other methods[1] but they doesn't work.

My Question: How can I convert the OpenCV Homography, so I can use
glMultMatrixf to get right transformed Images.

[1]http://www.aiqus.com/questions/24699/from-2d-homography-of-2-planes-to-3d-rotation-of-opengl-camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So an `H` matrix is the transformation of 1 point on plane one to another point on plane 2.

```
 X1 = H*X2
```

When you use `warpHomography` in opencv you are putting the points in the perceptive of plane 2.

The matrix (or image mat) that you get out of that `warping` is the texture you should use when applying to the surface.

Comment: @ilt Haha! awesome. Don't forget to click the check box(under the updown arrow) if it was what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Your extension of the 3x3 homography to 4x4 is wrong. The most naive approach which will *somewhat* work would be an extension of the form

```
     h11 h12 h13             h11 h12 0 h13
H =  h21 h22 h23   ->   H' = h21 h22 0 h23 
     h31 h32 h32             0   0   1  0
                             h31 h32 0 h33
```

The problem with this approach is that while it gives the correct result for `x` and `y`, it will distort `z`, since the modified `w` component affects all coordinates. If the z coordinate matters, you need a different approach.

In [this paper](http://web.media.mit.edu/~raskar/UNC/Planar/raskarImmDisplay.pdf), an approximation is proposed which will minimize the effects on the depth (see equation 5, you also will need to normalize your homography so that `h33=1`). However, this approximation will only work well enough for small distortions. If you have some extreme trapezoid distorion, that approch will also fail. In that case, a 2-pass approach of rendering into the texture and and applying the 2D distortion is possible.

With the modern programmable pipeline, one could also deal with this in one pass by undistorting the `z` coordinate in the fragment shader (but that can have some negative impact on performance on its own).

Comment: Do you have any code example for the shaders approach?